# Switch on data in groups of 4

Tags: c#

I have an object (converted to JSON data below). I need to iterate over it and process only the items where the "QUESTION_SECTION_ID" = 51.
I need to parse them into these 4 variables
`Revenue_Code`, `Funding_Source`, `Amount`, `Percent_Of_Funding`
 similar to this:

```
foreach(var question in qbs.Questions)
{
    switch (question.QuestionIndex)
    {
        case 300: // Only process items 300, 304, 308, ... to 376
        case 304:
            Funding = new ExpandoObject();
            Funding.Revenue_Code = question.ANSWER_LOOKUP_OPTION_NAME;
            formData.Fundings.Add(Funding);
            break;
        case 301: // Only process items 301, 305, 309, ... to 377
        case 305:
            Funding = new ExpandoObject();
            Funding.Funding_Source = question.ANSWER_STRING;
            formData.Fundings.Add(Funding);
            break;
        case 302: // Only process items 302, 306, 310, ... to 378
        case 306:
            Funding = new ExpandoObject();
            Funding.Amount = question.ANSWER_FLOAT;
            formData.Fundings.Add(Funding);
            break;
        case 303: // Only process items 303, 307, 311, ... to 379
        case 307: 
            Funding = new ExpandoObject();
            Funding.Percent_Of_Funding = question.ANSWER_FLOAT / 100;
            formData.Fundings.Add(Funding);
            break;
    }
}
```

There will be from 1 to 20 sets of 4 questions in this QuestionSection. I know C# doesn't allow ranges as arguments in case's so how else could I do this without making the case's so long?

The first ID is 300, the last one would be ID 379.

```
{
   "QuestionSectionId":0,
   "QuestionSectionName":null,
   "Questions":[
      {
         "CorrectiveActionsRequired":null,
         "Discussion":null,
         "QuestionIndex":0,
         "IsReadOnly":false,
         "Index":0,
         "SectionIndex":0,
         "QuestionSectionSortOrder":0,
         "QuestionSortOrder":0,
         "ID":16,
         "QUESTION":null,
         "QUESTION_SECTION_ID":49,
         "IS_VISIBLE":false,
         "IS_GROUP_SECTION":false,
         "IS_MULTI_ANSWER":false,
         "SORT_ORDER":0,
         "START_DATE":null,
         "END_DATE":null,
         "ANSWER_DATA_TYPE":3,
         "ANSWER_INT":null,
         "AnswerIntString":null,
         "ANSWER_STRING":null,
         "ANSWER_TEXT":null,
         "ANSWER_FLOAT":null,
         "AnswerFloatString":null,
         "ANSWER_DATETIME":"2017-03-01T00:00:00",
         "FriendlyAnswerDateTime":"3/1/2017",
         "ANSWER_LOOKUP_OPTION_ID":null,
         "LOOKUP_GROUP_ID":null,
         "LookupGroup":null,
         "ANSWER_INDEX":null,
         "FORMAT_VALIDATION":null,
         "CALC_EXPRESSION":null,
         "IS_TOTALFIELD":false,
         "DISPLAY_NAME":null
      },
      {
         "CorrectiveActionsRequired":null,
         "Discussion":null,
         "QuestionIndex":0,
         "IsReadOnly":false,
         "Index":0,
         "SectionIndex":0,
         "QuestionSectionSortOrder":0,
         "QuestionSortOrder":0,
         "ID":199,
         "QUESTION":null,
         "QUESTION_SECTION_ID":49,
         "IS_VISIBLE":false,
         "IS_GROUP_SECTION":false,
         "IS_MULTI_ANSWER":false,
         "SORT_ORDER":0,
         "START_DATE":null,
         "END_DATE":null,
         "ANSWER_DATA_TYPE":3,
         "ANSWER_INT":null,
         "AnswerIntString":null,
         "ANSWER_STRING":null,
         "ANSWER_TEXT":null,
         "ANSWER_FLOAT":null,
         "AnswerFloatString":null,
         "ANSWER_DATETIME":"2017-08-31T00:00:00",
         "FriendlyAnswerDateTime":"8/31/2017",
         "ANSWER_LOOKUP_OPTION_ID":null,
         "LOOKUP_GROUP_ID":null,
         "LookupGroup":null,
         "ANSWER_INDEX":null,
         "FORMAT_VALIDATION":null,
         "CALC_EXPRESSION":null,
         "IS_TOTALFIELD":false,
         "DISPLAY_NAME":null
      },
      {
         "CorrectiveActionsRequired":null,
         "Discussion":null,
         "QuestionIndex":0,
         "IsReadOnly":false,
         "Index":0,
         "SectionIndex":0,
         "QuestionSectionSortOrder":0,
         "QuestionSortOrder":0,
         "ID":229,
         "QUESTION":null,
         "QUESTION_SECTION_ID":50,
         "IS_VISIBLE":false,
         "IS_GROUP_SECTION":false,
         "IS_MULTI_ANSWER":false,
         "SORT_ORDER":0,
         "START_DATE":null,
         "END_DATE":null,
         "ANSWER_DATA_TYPE":1,
         "ANSWER_INT":null,
         "AnswerIntString":null,
         "ANSWER_STRING":null,
         "ANSWER_TEXT":null,
         "ANSWER_FLOAT":null,
         "AnswerFloatString":null,
         "ANSWER_DATETIME":null,
         "FriendlyAnswerDateTime":"",
         "ANSWER_LOOKUP_OPTION_ID":null,
         "LOOKUP_GROUP_ID":null,
         "LookupGroup":null,
         "ANSWER_INDEX":null,
         "FORMAT_VALIDATION":null,
         "CALC_EXPRESSION":null,
         "IS_TOTALFIELD":false,
         "DISPLAY_NAME":null
      },
      {
         "CorrectiveActionsRequired":null,
         "Discussion":null,
         "QuestionIndex":0,
         "IsReadOnly":false,
         "Index":0,
         "SectionIndex":0,
         "QuestionSectionSortOrder":0,
         "QuestionSortOrder":0,
         "ID":231,
         "QUESTION":null,
         "QUESTION_SECTION_ID":50,
         "IS_VISIBLE":false,
         "IS_GROUP_SECTION":false,
         "IS_MULTI_ANSWER":false,
         "SORT_ORDER":0,
         "START_DATE":null,
         "END_DATE":null,
         "ANSWER_DATA_TYPE":4,
         "ANSWER_INT":null,
         "AnswerIntString":null,
         "ANSWER_STRING":null,
         "ANSWER_TEXT":null,
         "ANSWER_FLOAT":1921194.00,
         "AnswerFloatString":"1921194.00",
         "ANSWER_DATETIME":null,
         "FriendlyAnswerDateTime":"",
         "ANSWER_LOOKUP_OPTION_ID":null,
         "LOOKUP_GROUP_ID":null,
         "LookupGroup":null,
         "ANSWER_INDEX":null,
         "FORMAT_VALIDATION":null,
         "CALC_EXPRESSION":null,
         "IS_TOTALFIELD":false,
         "DISPLAY_NAME":null
      },
      {
         "CorrectiveActionsRequired":null,
         "Discussion":null,
         "QuestionIndex":0,
         "IsReadOnly":false,
         "Index":0,
         "SectionIndex":0,
         "QuestionSectionSortOrder":0,
         "QuestionSortOrder":0,
         "ID":232,
         "QUESTION":null,
         "QUESTION_SECTION_ID":50,
         "IS_VISIBLE":false,
         "IS_GROUP_SECTION":false,
         "IS_MULTI_ANSWER":false,
         "SORT_ORDER":0,
         "START_DATE":null,
         "END_DATE":null,
         "ANSWER_DATA_TYPE":4,
         "ANSWER_INT":null,
         "AnswerIntString":null,
         "ANSWER_STRING":null,
         "ANSWER_TEXT":null,
         "ANSWER_FLOAT":92.01,
         "AnswerFloatString":"92.01",
         "ANSWER_DATETIME":null,
         "FriendlyAnswerDateTime":"",
         "ANSWER_LOOKUP_OPTION_ID":null,
         "LOOKUP_GROUP_ID":null,
         "LookupGroup":null,
         "ANSWER_INDEX":null,
         "FORMAT_VALIDATION":null,
         "CALC_EXPRESSION":null,
         "IS_TOTALFIELD":false,
         "DISPLAY_NAME":null
      },
      {
         "CorrectiveActionsRequired":null,
         "Discussion":null,
         "QuestionIndex":0,
         "IsReadOnly":false,
         "Index":0,
         "SectionIndex":0,
         "QuestionSectionSortOrder":0,
         "QuestionSortOrder":0,
         "ID":300,
         "QUESTION":null,
         "QUESTION_SECTION_ID":8,
         "IS_VISIBLE":false,
         "IS_GROUP_SECTION":false,
         "IS_MULTI_ANSWER":false,
         "SORT_ORDER":0,
         "START_DATE":null,
         "END_DATE":null,
         "ANSWER_DATA_TYPE":5,
         "ANSWER_INT":null,
         "AnswerIntString":null,
         "ANSWER_STRING":null,
         "ANSWER_TEXT":null,
         "ANSWER_FLOAT":null,
         "AnswerFloatString":null,
         "ANSWER_DATETIME":null,
         "FriendlyAnswerDateTime":"",
         "ANSWER_LOOKUP_OPTION_ID":31,
         "LOOKUP_GROUP_ID":null,
         "LookupGroup":null,
         "ANSWER_INDEX":null,
         "FORMAT_VALIDATION":null,
         "CALC_EXPRESSION":null,
         "IS_TOTALFIELD":false,
         "DISPLAY_NAME":null
      },
      {
         "CorrectiveActionsRequired":null,
         "Discussion":null,
         "QuestionIndex":0,
         "IsReadOnly":false,
         "Index":0,
         "SectionIndex":0,
         "QuestionSectionSortOrder":0,
         "QuestionSortOrder":0,
         "ID":301,
         "QUESTION":null,
         "QUESTION_SECTION_ID":8,
         "IS_VISIBLE":false,
         "IS_GROUP_SECTION":false,
         "IS_MULTI_ANSWER":false,
         "SORT_ORDER":0,
         "START_DATE":null,
         "END_DATE":null,
         "ANSWER_DATA_TYPE":1,
         "ANSWER_INT":null,
         "AnswerIntString":null,
         "ANSWER_STRING":"Florida",
         "ANSWER_TEXT":null,
         "ANSWER_FLOAT":null,
         "AnswerFloatString":null,
         "ANSWER_DATETIME":null,
         "FriendlyAnswerDateTime":"",
         "ANSWER_LOOKUP_OPTION_ID":null,
         "LOOKUP_GROUP_ID":null,
         "LookupGroup":null,
         "ANSWER_INDEX":null,
         "FORMAT_VALIDATION":null,
         "CALC_EXPRESSION":null,
         "IS_TOTALFIELD":false,
         "DISPLAY_NAME":null
      },
      {
         "CorrectiveActionsRequired":null,
         "Discussion":null,
         "QuestionIndex":0,
         "IsReadOnly":false,
         "Index":0,
         "SectionIndex":0,
         "QuestionSectionSortOrder":0,
         "QuestionSortOrder":0,
         "ID":302,
         "QUESTION":null,
         "QUESTION_SECTION_ID":8,
         "IS_VISIBLE":false,
         "IS_GROUP_SECTION":false,
         "IS_MULTI_ANSWER":false,
         "SORT_ORDER":0,
         "START_DATE":null,
         "END_DATE":null,
         "ANSWER_DATA_TYPE":4,
         "ANSWER_INT":null,
         "AnswerIntString":null,
         "ANSWER_STRING":null,
         "ANSWER_TEXT":null,
         "ANSWER_FLOAT":125571.00,
         "AnswerFloatString":"125571.00",
         "ANSWER_DATETIME":null,
         "FriendlyAnswerDateTime":"",
         "ANSWER_LOOKUP_OPTION_ID":null,
         "LOOKUP_GROUP_ID":null,
         "LookupGroup":null,
         "ANSWER_INDEX":null,
         "FORMAT_VALIDATION":null,
         "CALC_EXPRESSION":null,
         "IS_TOTALFIELD":false,
         "DISPLAY_NAME":null
      },
      {
         "CorrectiveActionsRequired":null,
         "Discussion":null,
         "QuestionIndex":0,
         "IsReadOnly":false,
         "Index":0,
         "SectionIndex":0,
         "QuestionSectionSortOrder":0,
         "QuestionSortOrder":0,
         "ID":303,
         "QUESTION":null,
         "QUESTION_SECTION_ID":8,
         "IS_VISIBLE":false,
         "IS_GROUP_SECTION":false,
         "IS_MULTI_ANSWER":false,
         "SORT_ORDER":0,
         "START_DATE":null,
         "END_DATE":null,
         "ANSWER_DATA_TYPE":4,
         "ANSWER_INT":null,
         "AnswerIntString":null,
         "ANSWER_STRING":null,
         "ANSWER_TEXT":null,
         "ANSWER_FLOAT":6.01,
         "AnswerFloatString":"6.01",
         "ANSWER_DATETIME":null,
         "FriendlyAnswerDateTime":"",
         "ANSWER_LOOKUP_OPTION_ID":null,
         "LOOKUP_GROUP_ID":null,
         "LookupGroup":null,
         "ANSWER_INDEX":null,
         "FORMAT_VALIDATION":null,
         "CALC_EXPRESSION":null,
         "IS_TOTALFIELD":false,
         "DISPLAY_NAME":null
      },
      {
         "CorrectiveActionsRequired":null,
         "Discussion":null,
         "QuestionIndex":0,
         "IsReadOnly":false,
         "Index":0,
         "SectionIndex":0,
         "QuestionSectionSortOrder":0,
         "QuestionSortOrder":0,
         "ID":304,
         "QUESTION":null,
         "QUESTION_SECTION_ID":8,
         "IS_VISIBLE":false,
         "IS_GROUP_SECTION":false,
         "IS_MULTI_ANSWER":false,
         "SORT_ORDER":0,
         "START_DATE":null,
         "END_DATE":null,
         "ANSWER_DATA_TYPE":5,
         "ANSWER_INT":null,
         "AnswerIntString":null,
         "ANSWER_STRING":null,
         "ANSWER_TEXT":null,
         "ANSWER_FLOAT":null,
         "AnswerFloatString":null,
         "ANSWER_DATETIME":null,
         "FriendlyAnswerDateTime":"",
         "ANSWER_LOOKUP_OPTION_ID":31,
         "LOOKUP_GROUP_ID":null,
         "LookupGroup":null,
         "ANSWER_INDEX":null,
         "FORMAT_VALIDATION":null,
         "CALC_EXPRESSION":null,
         "IS_TOTALFIELD":false,
         "DISPLAY_NAME":null
      },
      {
         "CorrectiveActionsRequired":null,
         "Discussion":null,
         "QuestionIndex":0,
         "IsReadOnly":false,
         "Index":0,
         "SectionIndex":0,
         "QuestionSectionSortOrder":0,
         "QuestionSortOrder":0,
         "ID":305,
         "QUESTION":null,
         "QUESTION_SECTION_ID":8,
         "IS_VISIBLE":false,
         "IS_GROUP_SECTION":false,
         "IS_MULTI_ANSWER":false,
         "SORT_ORDER":0,
         "START_DATE":null,
         "END_DATE":null,
         "ANSWER_DATA_TYPE":1,
         "ANSWER_INT":null,
         "AnswerIntString":null,
         "ANSWER_STRING":"Georgia",
         "ANSWER_TEXT":null,
         "ANSWER_FLOAT":null,
         "AnswerFloatString":null,
         "ANSWER_DATETIME":null,
         "FriendlyAnswerDateTime":"",
         "ANSWER_LOOKUP_OPTION_ID":null,
         "LOOKUP_GROUP_ID":null,
         "LookupGroup":null,
         "ANSWER_INDEX":null,
         "FORMAT_VALIDATION":null,
         "CALC_EXPRESSION":null,
         "IS_TOTALFIELD":false,
         "DISPLAY_NAME":null
      },
      {
         "CorrectiveActionsRequired":null,
         "Discussion":null,
         "QuestionIndex":0,
         "IsReadOnly":false,
         "Index":0,
         "SectionIndex":0,
         "QuestionSectionSortOrder":0,
         "QuestionSortOrder":0,
         "ID":306,
         "QUESTION":null,
         "QUESTION_SECTION_ID":8,
         "IS_VISIBLE":false,
         "IS_GROUP_SECTION":false,
         "IS_MULTI_ANSWER":false,
         "SORT_ORDER":0,
         "START_DATE":null,
         "END_DATE":null,
         "ANSWER_DATA_TYPE":4,
         "ANSWER_INT":null,
         "AnswerIntString":null,
         "ANSWER_STRING":null,
         "ANSWER_TEXT":null,
         "ANSWER_FLOAT":41250.00,
         "AnswerFloatString":"41250.00",
         "ANSWER_DATETIME":null,
         "FriendlyAnswerDateTime":"",
         "ANSWER_LOOKUP_OPTION_ID":null,
         "LOOKUP_GROUP_ID":null,
         "LookupGroup":null,
         "ANSWER_INDEX":null,
         "FORMAT_VALIDATION":null,
         "CALC_EXPRESSION":null,
         "IS_TOTALFIELD":false,
         "DISPLAY_NAME":null
      },
      {
         "CorrectiveActionsRequired":null,
         "Discussion":null,
         "QuestionIndex":0,
         "IsReadOnly":false,
         "Index":0,
         "SectionIndex":0,
         "QuestionSectionSortOrder":0,
         "QuestionSortOrder":0,
         "ID":307,
         "QUESTION":null,
         "QUESTION_SECTION_ID":8,
         "IS_VISIBLE":false,
         "IS_GROUP_SECTION":false,
         "IS_MULTI_ANSWER":false,
         "SORT_ORDER":0,
         "START_DATE":null,
         "END_DATE":null,
         "ANSWER_DATA_TYPE":4,
         "ANSWER_INT":null,
         "AnswerIntString":null,
         "ANSWER_STRING":null,
         "ANSWER_TEXT":null,
         "ANSWER_FLOAT":1.98,
         "AnswerFloatString":"1.98",
         "ANSWER_DATETIME":null,
         "FriendlyAnswerDateTime":"",
         "ANSWER_LOOKUP_OPTION_ID":null,
         "LOOKUP_GROUP_ID":null,
         "LookupGroup":null,
         "ANSWER_INDEX":null,
         "FORMAT_VALIDATION":null,
         "CALC_EXPRESSION":null,
         "IS_TOTALFIELD":false,
         "DISPLAY_NAME":null
      },
      {
         "CorrectiveActionsRequired":null,
         "Discussion":null,
         "QuestionIndex":0,
         "IsReadOnly":false,
         "Index":0,
         "SectionIndex":0,
         "QuestionSectionSortOrder":0,
         "QuestionSortOrder":0,
         "ID":223,
         "QUESTION":null,
         "QUESTION_SECTION_ID":51,
         "IS_VISIBLE":false,
         "IS_GROUP_SECTION":false,
         "IS_MULTI_ANSWER":false,
         "SORT_ORDER":0,
         "START_DATE":null,
         "END_DATE":null,
         "ANSWER_DATA_TYPE":4,
         "ANSWER_INT":null,
         "AnswerIntString":null,
         "ANSWER_STRING":null,
         "ANSWER_TEXT":null,
         "ANSWER_FLOAT":166821.00,
         "AnswerFloatString":"166821.00",
         "ANSWER_DATETIME":null,
         "FriendlyAnswerDateTime":"",
         "ANSWER_LOOKUP_OPTION_ID":null,
         "LOOKUP_GROUP_ID":null,
         "LookupGroup":null,
         "ANSWER_INDEX":null,
         "FORMAT_VALIDATION":null,
         "CALC_EXPRESSION":null,
         "IS_TOTALFIELD":false,
         "DISPLAY_NAME":null
      },
      {
         "CorrectiveActionsRequired":null,
         "Discussion":null,
         "QuestionIndex":0,
         "IsReadOnly":false,
         "Index":0,
         "SectionIndex":0,
         "QuestionSectionSortOrder":0,
         "QuestionSortOrder":0,
         "ID":224,
         "QUESTION":null,
         "QUESTION_SECTION_ID":51,
         "IS_VISIBLE":false,
         "IS_GROUP_SECTION":false,
         "IS_MULTI_ANSWER":false,
         "SORT_ORDER":0,
         "START_DATE":null,
         "END_DATE":null,
         "ANSWER_DATA_TYPE":4,
         "ANSWER_INT":null,
         "AnswerIntString":null,
         "ANSWER_STRING":null,
         "ANSWER_TEXT":null,
         "ANSWER_FLOAT":7.99,
         "AnswerFloatString":"7.99",
         "ANSWER_DATETIME":null,
         "FriendlyAnswerDateTime":"",
         "ANSWER_LOOKUP_OPTION_ID":null,
         "LOOKUP_GROUP_ID":null,
         "LookupGroup":null,
         "ANSWER_INDEX":null,
         "FORMAT_VALIDATION":null,
         "CALC_EXPRESSION":null,
         "IS_TOTALFIELD":false,
         "DISPLAY_NAME":null
      },
      {
         "CorrectiveActionsRequired":null,
         "Discussion":null,
         "QuestionIndex":0,
         "IsReadOnly":false,
         "Index":0,
         "SectionIndex":0,
         "QuestionSectionSortOrder":0,
         "QuestionSortOrder":0,
         "ID":225,
         "QUESTION":null,
         "QUESTION_SECTION_ID":51,
         "IS_VISIBLE":false,
         "IS_GROUP_SECTION":false,
         "IS_MULTI_ANSWER":false,
         "SORT_ORDER":0,
         "START_DATE":null,
         "END_DATE":null,
         "ANSWER_DATA_TYPE":4,
         "ANSWER_INT":null,
         "AnswerIntString":null,
         "ANSWER_STRING":null,
         "ANSWER_TEXT":null,
         "ANSWER_FLOAT":2088015.00,
         "AnswerFloatString":"2088015.00",
         "ANSWER_DATETIME":null,
         "FriendlyAnswerDateTime":"",
         "ANSWER_LOOKUP_OPTION_ID":null,
         "LOOKUP_GROUP_ID":null,
         "LookupGroup":null,
         "ANSWER_INDEX":null,
         "FORMAT_VALIDATION":null,
         "CALC_EXPRESSION":null,
         "IS_TOTALFIELD":false,
         "DISPLAY_NAME":null
      },
      {
         "CorrectiveActionsRequired":null,
         "Discussion":null,
         "QuestionIndex":0,
         "IsReadOnly":false,
         "Index":0,
         "SectionIndex":0,
         "QuestionSectionSortOrder":0,
         "QuestionSortOrder":0,
         "ID":226,
         "QUESTION":null,
         "QUESTION_SECTION_ID":51,
         "IS_VISIBLE":false,
         "IS_GROUP_SECTION":false,
         "IS_MULTI_ANSWER":false,
         "SORT_ORDER":0,
         "START_DATE":null,
         "END_DATE":null,
         "ANSWER_DATA_TYPE":4,
         "ANSWER_INT":null,
         "AnswerIntString":null,
         "ANSWER_STRING":null,
         "ANSWER_TEXT":null,
         "ANSWER_FLOAT":100.00,
         "AnswerFloatString":"100.00",
         "ANSWER_DATETIME":null,
         "FriendlyAnswerDateTime":"",
         "ANSWER_LOOKUP_OPTION_ID":null,
         "LOOKUP_GROUP_ID":null,
         "LookupGroup":null,
         "ANSWER_INDEX":null,
         "FORMAT_VALIDATION":null,
         "CALC_EXPRESSION":null,
         "IS_TOTALFIELD":false,
         "DISPLAY_NAME":null
      },
      {
         "CorrectiveActionsRequired":null,
         "Discussion":null,
         "QuestionIndex":0,
         "IsReadOnly":false,
         "Index":0,
         "SectionIndex":0,
         "QuestionSectionSortOrder":0,
         "QuestionSortOrder":0,
         "ID":17,
         "QUESTION":null,
         "QUESTION_SECTION_ID":51,
         "IS_VISIBLE":false,
         "IS_GROUP_SECTION":false,
         "IS_MULTI_ANSWER":false,
         "SORT_ORDER":0,
         "START_DATE":null,
         "END_DATE":null,
         "ANSWER_DATA_TYPE":4,
         "ANSWER_INT":null,
         "AnswerIntString":null,
         "ANSWER_STRING":null,
         "ANSWER_TEXT":null,
         "ANSWER_FLOAT":166821.00,
         "AnswerFloatString":"166821.00",
         "ANSWER_DATETIME":null,
         "FriendlyAnswerDateTime":"",
         "ANSWER_LOOKUP_OPTION_ID":null,
         "LOOKUP_GROUP_ID":null,
         "LookupGroup":null,
         "ANSWER_INDEX":null,
         "FORMAT_VALIDATION":null,
         "CALC_EXPRESSION":null,
         "IS_TOTALFIELD":false,
         "DISPLAY_NAME":null
      },
      {
         "CorrectiveActionsRequired":null,
         "Discussion":null,
         "QuestionIndex":0,
         "IsReadOnly":false,
         "Index":0,
         "SectionIndex":0,
         "QuestionSectionSortOrder":0,
         "QuestionSortOrder":0,
         "ID":227,
         "QUESTION":null,
         "QUESTION_SECTION_ID":51,
         "IS_VISIBLE":false,
         "IS_GROUP_SECTION":false,
         "IS_MULTI_ANSWER":false,
         "SORT_ORDER":0,
         "START_DATE":null,
         "END_DATE":null,
         "ANSWER_DATA_TYPE":4,
         "ANSWER_INT":null,
         "AnswerIntString":null,
         "ANSWER_STRING":null,
         "ANSWER_TEXT":null,
         "ANSWER_FLOAT":317744.32,
         "AnswerFloatString":"317744.32",
         "ANSWER_DATETIME":null,
         "FriendlyAnswerDateTime":"",
         "ANSWER_LOOKUP_OPTION_ID":null,
         "LOOKUP_GROUP_ID":null,
         "LookupGroup":null,
         "ANSWER_INDEX":null,
         "FORMAT_VALIDATION":null,
         "CALC_EXPRESSION":null,
         "IS_TOTALFIELD":false,
         "DISPLAY_NAME":null
      },
      {
         "CorrectiveActionsRequired":null,
         "Discussion":null,
         "QuestionIndex":0,
         "IsReadOnly":false,
         "Index":0,
         "SectionIndex":0,
         "QuestionSectionSortOrder":0,
         "QuestionSortOrder":0,
         "ID":228,
         "QUESTION":null,
         "QUESTION_SECTION_ID":51,
         "IS_VISIBLE":false,
         "IS_GROUP_SECTION":false,
         "IS_MULTI_ANSWER":false,
         "SORT_ORDER":0,
         "START_DATE":null,
         "END_DATE":null,
         "ANSWER_DATA_TYPE":4,
         "ANSWER_INT":null,
         "AnswerIntString":null,
         "ANSWER_STRING":null,
         "ANSWER_TEXT":null,
         "ANSWER_FLOAT":-150923.32,
         "AnswerFloatString":"-150923.32",
         "ANSWER_DATETIME":null,
         "FriendlyAnswerDateTime":"",
         "ANSWER_LOOKUP_OPTION_ID":null,
         "LOOKUP_GROUP_ID":null,
         "LookupGroup":null,
         "ANSWER_INDEX":null,
         "FORMAT_VALIDATION":null,
         "CALC_EXPRESSION":null,
         "IS_TOTALFIELD":false,
         "DISPLAY_NAME":null
      }
   ],
   "Answers":null
}
```

Comment: Not granular enough for my purposes, please read the entire question. Still have to have 4 if statements with 20 conditions in each.

Comment: looks like you could even refactor out the creation and adding of the object.

Comment: @DanielA.White, what do you suggest?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They seem to be grouped by the `(<QuestionIndex> - <base>) mod 4`:

```
foreach(var question in qbs.Questions)
{
    int switchKey = (question.QuestionIndex - 300) % 4;
    switch (switchKey)
    {
        case 0:
            Funding = new ExpandoObject();
            Funding.Revenue_Code = question.ANSWER_LOOKUP_OPTION_NAME;
            formData.Fundings.Add(Funding);
            break;
        case 1:
            Funding = new ExpandoObject();
            Funding.Funding_Source = question.ANSWER_STRING;
            formData.Fundings.Add(Funding);
            break;
        case 2:
            Funding = new ExpandoObject();
            Funding.Amount = question.ANSWER_FLOAT;
            formData.Fundings.Add(Funding);
            break;
        case 3:
            Funding = new ExpandoObject();
            Funding.Percent_Of_Funding = question.ANSWER_FLOAT / 100;
            formData.Fundings.Add(Funding);
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah I thought about that but wasn't sure how to do the math...;-)

Comment: what would you do if a number fell outside of the pattern?

Answer (score 1):

I would build out `HashSet<int>`s that have the values. That way you can call `set.Contains(value)`.

```
// You could make this readonly and store it somewhere else as needed
HashSet<int> set1 = new HashSet<int>();
// add values in the ranges you care about

// in your app
if (set1.Contains(question.QuestionIndex)) {
   // ...
}
```

Comment: Do you have example?